# Gerrit reverse proxy extra trailing slash

Tags: apache, redirect, gerrit

**Have the followning conf in gerrit.config:** 
https://gerrit.camel.se/

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = git
        #canonicalWebUrl = http://search.ge

    rrit.camel.se:9095/
            canonicalWebUrl = https://search.gerrit.camel.se:443/
            serverId = 13aeea07-6697-4493-bf90-41f9457f4598
            ui = polygerrit
            enableGwtUi = true
    [auth]
            type = OAUTH
            gitBasicAuthPolicy = HTTP
    [httpd]
            listenUrl = proxy-http://localhost:8085/

**the following conf in apache2:**


   ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    LISTEN 9095
    <VirtualHost *:9095>
              ServerName search.gerrit.camel.se
              ServerAdmin sysadm@camel.com


              ProxyVia Off

              <Proxy *>
                Require all granted
              </Proxy>
              #AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
              AllowEncodedSlashes On
              ProxyPass / http://localhost:8085 nocanon
              ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8085
              RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"

             ErrorLog /var/log/gerrit/error.log
             CustomLog /var/log/gerrit/access.log common

    </VirtualHost>


    <VirtualHost *:443>
              ServerName search.gerrit.camel.se
              ServerAdmin sysadm@camel.com
              SSLEngine on

              SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/gerrit.camel.se/fullchain.pem
              SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/gerrit.camel.se/privkey.pem



              #AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
              AllowEncodedSlashes On
              ProxyPass / http://localhost:8085/ nocanon
              ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8085/
              RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"


             ErrorLog /var/log/gerrit/error.log
             CustomLog /var/log/gerrit/access.log common

    </VirtualHost>
```

when I write https://search.gerrit.camel.se works fine
**the qusetion:**
when I wite http://search.gerrit.camel.se it redirectes me to https://search.gerrit.camel.se// with extra slash /
How Can I fix that

Comment: Can you try removing the trailing slash in the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` in your Apache config?

Comment: AllowEncodedSlashes On
          ProxyPass / http://localhost:8085 nocanon
          ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8085
If I do as above in <VirtualHost *:443> section. then it give me https://search.gerrit.camel.se// with two slashes again. bu additionally no content whe I browse http://search.gerrit.camel.se with https.